# How to make two properties animate with different durations

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animated div and I animate 2 properties `right:100px` and `bottom:80px`.

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_j/s8gzvf5f/)</kbd>

Like this;

```
.demo{
    background: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT7/eoj/dT7eojnT9.jpeg) no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width:90px;
    animation: smileDog 3s ease-in-out infinite;
    position: absolute;
    background-size:100%
}
@keyframes smileDog{
    from{right:0px;bottom: 0px;}
    to{right:100px;bottom: 80px;}
}
```

Now my question is that, can I manage the animation timing in a single keyframe? I mean `right:100px` should move in 3s and `bottom:80px` move in  10s. Both the moves should start and happen simultaneously but with different durations. **Is it possible ?**

If no then how can I do that?

Comment: You can do with just one animation but it depends on what is the exact requirement. Should it move right and then bottom or move both at same time but different durations?

Comment: Ya you are right ,I want that at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 keyframes then:

```
.demo{
    background: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT7/eoj/dT7eojnT9.jpeg) no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width:90px;
    animation: smileDogRight 3s ease-in-out infinite,
               smileDogBottom 10s ease-in-out infinite;
    position: absolute;
    background-size:100%
}
@keyframes smileDogRight{
    from{right:0px;}
    to{right:100px;}
}
@keyframes smileDogBottom{
    from{bottom: 0px;}
    to{bottom: 80px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with just a single `animation` by doing the following:

1. Change the `animation-duration` to `10s` (which is the maximum of the two animation effects).
2. Instead of `from` and `to` keyframe rules, use percentages. For example, if the `right: 0px` to `right: 100px` needs to happen in 3s then it means `30%` of the animation duration. So at `30%` specify `right: 100px` but do not specify anything for the `bottom`.
3. At `100%` (which is nothing but `10s`) the full animation effect for the `bottom:0px` to `bottom: 80px` must also complete. So, for that keyframe rule specify `right: 100px` and `bottom: 80px`.
4. Doing the above would have an arbitrary movement of the `bottom` till `3s` but if you want it to exactly move 30% of the full movement within `3s` then add `bottom: 24px` (30% of 80px) at the `30%` keyframe rule.

```css
.demo{
    background: url(http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/dT7/eoj/dT7eojnT9.jpeg) no-repeat;
    height: 100px;
    width:90px;
    animation: smileDog 10s ease-in-out infinite;
    position: absolute;
    background-size:100%
}
@keyframes smileDog{
    0%{right:0px;bottom: 0px;}
    30%{right:100px;}
    100%{right:100px;bottom: 80px;}
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/s8gzvf5f/3/) - The demo uses `-webkit-` prefixes.

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/s8gzvf5f/2/) - For the alternate approach mentioned in Point 4.